# Google Chrome does not sync history properly

Tags: google-chrome, sync, history

I am trying to switch all of my history from Chrome to a new laptop. The issue is that even though I have synced my history on both devices, I can only access the history available on that specific device. How can I access all of my browsing history across all devices?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Chrome Sync has been behaving very erratically the last 2 weeks. In my case, my bookmarks are not sync-ing across devices.